# JavaMail on Android throwing a file not found exception

Tags: java, android, jakarta-mail

So I'm trying to send an email on android using the Javamail android library (https://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/) and everything compiles and runs from the sample code I found with minor tweaks (asynctask, etc). However, no emails would be sent, and after enabling debugging, I'm noticing a few exceptions being thrown, the first of which is that /system/lib/javamail.providers cannot be found. Has anyone dealt with this issue using javamail on android and can weigh in?

EmailActivity.java :

```
package com.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class EmailActivity extends Activity {

/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */
@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button addImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
    addImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            Email m = new Email("fromtest@gmail.com", "password");
            String[] toArr = {"totest@gmail.com"};
            m.set_to(toArr);
            m.set_from("fromtest@gmail.com");
            m.set_subject("Subject");
            m.setBody("Email body.");

            try {
                // m.addAttachment("/sdcard/filelocation");
                boolean sent = m.send();
                if (sent) {
                    Toast.makeText(EmailActivity.this, "Email was sent successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(EmailActivity.this, "Email was not sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //Toast.makeText(MailApp.this, "There was a problem sending the email.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.e("MailApp", "Could not send email", e);
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Email.java:

```
package com.myapplication;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Message;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.activation.CommandMap;
import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.activation.FileDataSource;
import javax.activation.MailcapCommandMap;
import javax.mail.BodyPart;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;


public class Email extends javax.mail.Authenticator {
private String _user;
private String _pass;


public String[] get_to() {
    return _to;
}

public void set_to(String[] _to) {
    this._to = _to;
}

public String get_user() {
    return _user;
}

public void set_user(String _user) {
    this._user = _user;
}

public String get_pass() {
    return _pass;
}

public void set_pass(String _pass) {
    this._pass = _pass;
}

public String get_from() {
    return _from;
}

public void set_from(String _from) {
    this._from = _from;
}

public String get_port() {
    return _port;
}

public void set_port(String _port) {
    this._port = _port;
}

public String get_sport() {
    return _sport;
}

public void set_sport(String _sport) {
    this._sport = _sport;
}

public String get_host() {
    return _host;
}

public void set_host(String _host) {
    this._host = _host;
}

public String get_subject() {
    return _subject;
}

public void set_subject(String _subject) {
    this._subject = _subject;
}

public String get_body() {
    return _body;
}

public void set_body(String _body) {
    this._body = _body;
}

public boolean is_auth() {
    return _auth;
}

public void set_auth(boolean _auth) {
    this._auth = _auth;
}

public boolean is_debuggable() {
    return _debuggable;
}

public void set_debuggable(boolean _debuggable) {
    this._debuggable = _debuggable;
}

public Multipart get_multipart() {
    return _multipart;
}

public void set_multipart(Multipart _multipart) {
    this._multipart = _multipart;
}

private String[] _to;
private String _from;

private String _port;
private String _sport;

private String _host;

private String _subject;
private String _body;

private boolean _auth;

private boolean _debuggable;

private Multipart _multipart;


public Email() {
    _host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // default smtp server
    _port = "465"; // default smtp port
    _sport = "465"; // default  socketfactory port

    _user = ""; // username
    _pass = ""; // password
    _from = ""; // email sent from
    _subject = ""; // email subject
    _body = ""; // email body

    _debuggable = true; // debug mode on or off - default off
    _auth = true; // smtp authentication - default on

    _multipart = new MimeMultipart();

    // There is something wrong with MailCap, javamail can not find a handler for the multipart/mixed part, so this bit needs to be added.
    MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap();
    mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html");
    mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml");
    mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain");
    mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed");
    mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822");
    CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc);
}

public Email(String user, String pass) {
    this();

    _user = user;
    _pass = pass;
}

public boolean send() throws Exception {
    Properties props = _setProperties();

    if(!_user.equals("") && !_pass.equals("") && _to.length > 0 && !_from.equals("") && !_subject.equals("") && !_body.equals("")) {
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, this);

        MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);

        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(_from));

        InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[_to.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < _to.length; i++) {
            addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(_to[i]);
        }
        msg.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, addressTo);

        msg.setSubject(_subject);
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());

        // setup message body
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageBodyPart.setText(_body);
        _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        // Put parts in message
        msg.setContent(_multipart);

        // send email
        new LongRunningTask().execute(msg);

        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

//   public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception {
//        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
//        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
//        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
//        messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);

//        _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
//  }

@Override
public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
    return new PasswordAuthentication(_user, _pass);
}

private Properties _setProperties() {
    Properties props = new Properties();

    props.put("mail.smtp.host", _host);

    if(_debuggable) {
        props.put("mail.debug", "true");
    }

    if(_auth) {
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    }

    props.put("mail.smtp.port", _port);
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", _sport);
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

    return props;
}

// the getters and setters
public String getBody() {
    return _body;
}

public void setBody(String _body) {
    this._body = _body;
}


private class LongRunningTask extends AsyncTask <MimeMessage, Void, Void>{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(MimeMessage... params) {
        MimeMessage msg = params[0];
        try {
            Transport.send(msg);
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}

// more of the getters and setters …..



 }
```

Here is what the debug is outputting:

```
com.myapplication I/System.out﹕ DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.4.1
com.myapplication I/System.out﹕ DEBUG: not loading file: /system/lib/javamail.providers
com.myapplication I/System.out﹕ DEBUG: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /system/lib/javamail.providers: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
com.myapplication I/System.out﹕ DEBUG: !anyLoaded
com.myapplication I/System.out﹕ DEBUG: not loading resource: /META-INF/javamail.providers
com.myapplication I/System.out﹕ DEBUG: not loading resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers
com.myapplication I/System.out﹕ DEBUG: failed to load any providers, using defaults
com.myapplication I/System.out﹕ DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers
com.myapplication I/System.out﹕ DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc.,1.4.1], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc.,1.4.1], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc.,1.4.1], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc.,1.4.1], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Sun Microsystems, Inc.,1.4.1], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc.,1.4.1]}
com.myapplication I/System.out﹕ DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Sun Microsystems, Inc.,1.4.1], pop3s=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc.,1.4.1], imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc.,1.4.1], smtps=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc.,1.4.1], imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc.,1.4.1], smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc.,1.4.1]}
com.myapplication I/System.out﹕ DEBUG: not loading resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
com.myapplication I/System.out﹕ DEBUG: !anyLoaded
com.myapplication I/System.out﹕ DEBUG: not loading resource: /META-INF/javamail.address.map
com.myapplication I/System.out﹕ DEBUG: not loading file: /system/lib/javamail.address.map
com.myapplication I/System.out﹕ DEBUG: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /system/lib/javamail.address.map: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
com.myapplication I/System.out﹕ DEBUG: failed to load address map, using defaults
com.myapplication I/System.out﹕ DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc.,1.4.1]
com.myapplication I/System.out﹕ DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
com.myapplication I/System.out﹕ DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
com.myapplication I/System.out﹕ DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 465, isSSL false
com.myapplication w/System.err﹕ javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465;
com.myapplication w/System.err﹕ nested exception is:
com.myapplication w/System.err﹕ java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to smtp.gmail.com/74.125.196.108 (port 465): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
com.myapplication w/System.err﹕ at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1391)
com.myapplication w/System.err﹕ at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:412)
com.myapplication w/System.err﹕ at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:310)
com.myapplication w/System.err﹕ at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:169)
com.myapplication w/System.err﹕ at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:118)
com.myapplication w/System.err﹕ at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:188)
com.myapplication w/System.err﹕ at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:118)
com.myapplication w/System.err﹕ at com.myapplication.Email$LongRunningTask.doInBackground(Email.java:265)
com.myapplication w/System.err﹕ at com.myapplication.Email$LongRunningTask.doInBackground(Email.java:260)
com.myapplication w/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
com.myapplication w/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
com.myapplication w/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
com.myapplication w/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
com.myapplication w/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
com.myapplication w/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
com.myapplication w/System.err﹕ Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to smtp.gmail.com/74.125.196.108 (port 465): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
com.myapplication w/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:114)
com.myapplication w/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
com.myapplication w/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:460)
com.myapplication w/System.err﹕ at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:833)
com.myapplication w/System.err﹕ at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:786)
com.myapplication w/System.err﹕ at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:233)
com.myapplication w/System.err﹕ at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:163)
com.myapplication w/System.err﹕ at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1359)
com.myapplication w/System.err﹕ ... 14 more
com.myapplication w/System.err﹕ Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
com.myapplication w/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
com.myapplication w/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:85)
com.myapplication w/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
com.myapplication w/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
```

Comment: Looks like the ports aren't open, Google port forward testing tools and see if the ports are open.

Answer (score 0):

1.Add this permission to your android manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

2.Check your port

3.You cannot do network operation from any UI activity in android, use AsyncTask to avoid network on main thread exception.

This link is complete answer for JavaMail on android:
[Sending Email in Android using JavaMail API without using the default/built-in app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a)

Comment: 1. I've got that in my android manifest, I should have mentioned that. My bad.

2. I've tried both of the recommended ports, still nothing.

3. I am using AsyncTask, and I'm not getting the AsyncTask on main thread exception anymore.

Do you know how to address the file not found exception?

Comment: The "file not found" exception is normal.  JavaMail looks for configuration files in several places.  Normally it will only find the configuration files in the JavaMail jar file, but you can put configuration files in other places if you need to.